# Add different Namespace prefixes and attributes to XML in Net Core

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I'd like to add multiple namespace prefixes and attributes to an existing XML in Net6 Core API.
I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note xmlns="http://test.co.uk" xmlns:temp="http://tes007.co.uk" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <Title>Hello</Title>
  </Header>
  <PutData>
  <Credentials>
    <Username>Test</Username>
    <Password>1234</Password>
  </Credentials>
  <Payload>
      <Filename>test.xml</Filename>
      <FileType>Xml</FileType>
  </Payload>
  <message>
     <title>Title1</title>
     <body></body>
  </message>
  </PutData>
</note>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note xmlns="http://test.co.uk" xmlns:temp="http://tes007.co.uk" xmlns:xsi="http://test0010.com.br">
  <xsi:Header>
    <Title>Hello</Title>
  </xsi:Header>
  <temp:PutData>
  <Credentials>
    <Username>Test</Username>
    <Password>1234</Password>
  </Credentials>
  <Payload>
      <Filename>test.xml</Filename>
      <FileType>Xml</FileType>
  </Payload>
  <message Type="TEST007">
     <title>Title1</title>
     <body></body>
  </message>
  </temp:PutData>
</note>
```

I have tried something like:

```
XmlDocument doc = XmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
var xPath = "//*"  //all nodes
foreach(XmlElement node in doc.SelectNodes(xPath))
{
   if(node.Name == "Header")
    {
       node.Prefix = "xsi";
       node.RemoveAttribute("xmlns");
    }
   if(node.Name == "PutData")
    {
       node.Prefix = "temp";
       node.RemoveAttribute("xmlns");
    }
}
```

The above worked partially for the prefixes.

I know we have similar questions to this, but none worked for me. I's appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: (1) What you want is not well-formed as it has mismatched start and end tags.  (2) Never say "none worked for me"; show what you tried, what the results were, and how the results differed from your goal.  (3) Don't use the `xsi` namespace prefix for a random namespace like that; it is conventionally reserved for `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. (4) Without a [mcve], this reads like a write-code-for-me request, which is not going to go over well here.

Comment: "I have the following:"  Did you obtain it from API  or created using c#? Pls show us the code

Comment: Hi, I've created it using C#.  first got the payload request and converted it into Json object and then convert into XML file.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: Hi kjhughes, sorry for the xml mal formation,  I was rushing it bit, as I need to solve this issue asap.  I have edited it.

Comment: .Net Framework supports XSLT 1.0 out-of-the-box. Like @MichaelKay already pointed out, it is better to use XSLT for the task.

Comment: I would not expect a DOM implementation like System.Xml.XmlDocument/XmlElement/Node to allow you to change the names of nodes once constructed, and both prefix and namespace are essential parts of the name. On the other hand, System.Xml.Linq.XNode/XElement, I think, were designed to make up for the DOM "shortcoming" and allow changing the name: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/change-namespace-entire-xml-tree. Therefore, in the .NET world, if you want to do a name change after constructing the tree in situ on the members of the tree, use System.Xml.Linq.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT 3.0 transformation changes the namespace of the PutData element and leaves everything else unchanged:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="*:PutData">
    <xsl:element name="temp:PutData" namespace="http://tes007.co.uk">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

It can also be done using XSLT 1.0 if you prefer to stick to Microsoft-supplied tools.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I am after something using C#, eg: XmlDocument

Comment: If you want to do it the hard way, I'm afraid you'll have to find someone else to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter pointed out, changing an element's name/namespace with the `System.Xml` API in .NET can't do what you want, you have to use the `System.Xml.Linq` API (`XDocument`, `XElement` etc.):

```
var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <note xmlns=\"http://test.co.uk\" xmlns:temp=\"http://tes007.co.uk\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"> <Header> <Title>Hello</Title> </Header> <PutData> <Credentials> <Username>Test</Username> <Password>1234</Password> </Credentials> <Payload> <Filename>test.xml</Filename> <FileType>Xml</FileType> </Payload> <message> <title>Title1</title> <body></body> </message> </PutData> </note>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var xdocAttributes = xdoc.Root.Attributes();
var xsiNs = xdocAttributes.First(n => n.Name.LocalName == "xsi");
var tempNs = xdocAttributes.First(n => n.Name.LocalName == "temp");
xsiNs.Value = "http://test0010.com.br";

var header = xdoc.Descendants().First(d => d.Name.LocalName == "Header");
header.Name = XName.Get("Header", xsiNs.Value);

var putData = xdoc.Descendants().First(d => d.Name.LocalName == "PutData");
putData.Name = XName.Get("PutData", tempNs.Value);

var message = xdoc.Descendants().First(m => m.Name.LocalName == "message");
message.Add(new XAttribute("Type", "TEST007"));
```

Using `xdoc.ToString()` will give you:

```
<note xmlns="http://test.co.uk" xmlns:temp="http://tes007.co.uk" xmlns:xsi="http://test0010.com.br">
  <xsi:Header>
    <Title>Hello</Title>
  </xsi:Header>
  <temp:PutData>
    <Credentials>
      <Username>Test</Username>
      <Password>1234</Password>
    </Credentials>
    <Payload>
      <Filename>test.xml</Filename>
      <FileType>Xml</FileType>
    </Payload>
    <message Type="TEST007">
      <title>Title1</title>
      <body></body>
    </message>
  </temp:PutData>
</note>
```